# How do I set up the Zurb Foundation icons?

Tags: css, icons, zurb-foundation, css-frameworks

I have downloaded the Zurb Foundation icon fonts files http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icon-fonts-3

I unzipped them and placed the /foundation-icons folder into my /css folder. Is this correct? I am trying to follow the documentation "How to use them" section and i can't figure out how to start using the classes.

I am doing this in my .html to call the classes.

```
<a class=".fi-social-facebook">Facebook</a>
```

so i assume i must of not configured/set up my file font properly.

**Update**: This is what my directory looks like... i am referencing it
 and this is how I am calling the class.

```
<i class="ft-social-facebook"></i><a href="#">Facebook</a>
<i class="ft-star"></i>
```

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: If anyone is looking for a reference to all of the icons themselves: http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icon-fonts-3#allicons

Comment: Classes start with `fi-` rather than `ft-`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Foundation icons use the `<i>` tags.  So you would have something like `<i class="fi-social-facebook"></i><a href="http://facebook.com">Facebook</a>`.

In the zip that you downloaded, there is a preview.html file.  Open it in your editor and look it over.  It will make a little more sense.

Also, their CSS file doesn't include sizes.  So when you use their examples to change the size (ex. `<i class="fi-calendar size-24"></i>`), nothing will change.  In looking at their preview.html file, they had those sizes defined in the header. So I copied them out and put them in my CSS and solved the issue. Here they are if you want to use them:

```
.size-12 { font-size: 12px; }
.size-14 { font-size: 14px; }
.size-16 { font-size: 16px; }
.size-18 { font-size: 18px; }
.size-21 { font-size: 21px; }
.size-24 { font-size: 24px; }
.size-36 { font-size: 36px; }
.size-48 { font-size: 48px; }
.size-60 { font-size: 60px; }
.size-72 { font-size: 72px; }
```

Answer (score 20):

Once you've downloaded the pack, you have to add to your `<head>` :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation-icons.css" />
```

And be sure that the `svgs` folder inside your `css` folder, and the rest of files inside your `css` folder too.

When you finish this set up, try this on your html:

```
<i class="fi-star"></i>
```

It should print a star.

---

Quickest solution, no installation required:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.min.css"/>
```

Other versions available at https://cdnjs.com/libraries/foundicons

Comment: Added copy paste answer using cdnjs

Answer (score 5):

I installed via `pip install django-zurb-foundation` and was running into the same problem `…/foundation/icons` worked, but I couldn't reference them in my actual project. What wound up working for me is adding the following to my project's `base.html`

```
{% load foundation_tags %}

{% block css %}
{% foundation_css 'foundation-icons' %}
{% endblock css %}
```

Which is effectively the same as [ManelMusti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3214644/manelmusti)'s answer, but handled in the template using the same technique as the example in `…/site_packages/foundation/templates/foundation/icons.html`

Answer (score 4):

The correct way is `<i class="fi-star"></i>` instead of `<i class="ft-star"></i>`

Comment: t vs i  Read closely.